# react - Complex Form with Multiple Object Depth

Tags: reactjs

I am fairly new to React so excuse me if this is a basic question. I found a lot of examples of forms with a flat structure (simple set of input fields) where there is one event handler that takes in an event, and updates the state based on the name field.

```
updateFormState: function (event) {
  var form = Object.assign({}, this.state.form);
  form[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
  this.setState({form: form});
}
```

However, I could not find an example where the form has a nested structure .. such as adding a list of address objects or if needed, to even go another level down of nested objects.  Looking up by the target name with a complex form, does not be a viable solution for updating the form state, since you need to include an array index and a nested structure.  Additionally, I would most likely want to delegate the nested field structure into different components passing along the change event handler from the parent component to other children components.

Can someone please provide the proper approach or even a live example on how to develop such a form in React.

Comment: If you have such complex data, it might be worth looking into a library like [Formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik) that makes the experience a lot more enjoyable.

Comment: Its funny that in KnockoutJS or Angular this would be a piece of cake, but in a popular framework like React it is painful